# How can I lowercase an array of strings at compile time in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have an array of strings like

```rust
const LANGUAGES: [&str; 3] = [
  "EN",
  "ES",
  "DE",
];
```

and I would like to lowercase them at compile time. How can I do that?

Comment: Doing anything like this would require either a procedural macro or a build script, neither of which are super simple solutions. Perhaps the problem you're trying to solve can be tackled another way?

Comment: Probably not what you really want, but you can use `lazy_static` to create static objects that run some initialization code the first time they're accessed.

Comment: What do you exactly want ? To have two separate arrays, one being built from the other one ? Or only one array in lowercase. If you're thinking about two separate arrays then you should consider using structs for consistency and code clarity.

Comment: Assuming you don't just do it manually because you have tons of text data that you copied into your sources... I'd just write a python script with regular expression substitutions to lowercase any strings in the sources that need it. It only needs to be done once...

Answer (score 0):

Using the `konst` and `const_str` package, we can achieve this by joining a slice into a single string, applying the `convert_ascii_case` macro to lowercase it, and then splitting the string by the same delimiter into a slice

With arrays,

```
const SIZE: usize = 3;
const LANGUAGES: [&str; SIZE] = ["EN", "ES", "DE"];
const LOWERED: [&str; SIZE] = {
    const SEPERATOR: &str = "|";
    const AS_SLICE: &[&str] = &LANGUAGES;
    const JOINED: &str = konst::string::str_join!(SEPERATOR, AS_SLICE);
    const LOWERED_JOINED: &str = const_str::convert_ascii_case!(lower, JOINED);
    const_str::split!(LOWERED_JOINED, SEPERATOR)
};
println!("{:#?}", LOWERED);
```

With slices,

```
const LANGUAGES: &[&str] = &["EN", "ES", "DE"];
const LOWERED: &[&str] = {
    const SEPERATOR: &str = "|";
    const JOINED: &str = konst::string::str_join!(SEPERATOR, LANGUAGES);
    const LOWERED_JOINED: &str = const_str::convert_ascii_case!(lower, JOINED);
    &const_str::split!(LOWERED_JOINED, SEPERATOR)
};
println!("{:#?}", LOWERED);
```

You may also want to look into `konst`'s `for_each` macro and the general idea of `const_eval`. But I have yet to construct a working example using that.